# Is possible to have a portable LMDB database?

Tags: database, portability, lmdb

According to https://blog.separateconcerns.com/2016-04-03-lmdb-format.html:

> The first thing to know is that the data.mdb format is
>   platform-specific, which means that you cannot necessarily open a
>   database created on a machine on another one. In practice, on ARM and
>   x86, the only thing you have to care about is whether the machine is
>   32 or 64 bits. On a 64 bit machine, you can read the data from a 32
>   bit database by exporting it to a text format using the mdb_dump
>   utility compiled in 32 bits and reimporting it with a 64 bits
>   mdb_load. With lua-mdb, you can read a 32 bits database directly by
>   passing the bits option to the constructor.

it can just copy/paste a database file between arch/operating systems. Is this true? Is possible to have a portable format?

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2607), given by the author of lmdb.

Comment: @kawing-chiu That answer appears to be for Monero specifically, not LMDB generally. Presumably, if Monero, which relies on LMDB, is portable across bit widths, then LMDB is too.

Comment: It'd be useful to get confirmation from @hyc.